# Is it possible to install facebook application for the user?

Tags: php, facebook

Is it possible to install facebook application on Users profile, I know that user can do it easily, but can we do it through the code?

Answer (score 2):

You can't install an app without the user's express consent. The must approve the installation before it can be installed. So, no, you can't force someone to install an app on Facebook.